# boolean masking to replace all strings containing only zero in Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling to understand why the following code does not work. Imagine I have the following dataframe, which has a column of type string which could contain string of any length. I want to replace all strings containing only '0' with Nan.

```
d = {'col1': ['carlo', 'luca', 'nanni', 'nanno', 'john' ], 
     'col2': ['0000',  '00',   '0',     '10000D','CO0123']}
dftest = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dftest
```

the visual df is:

```
    col1  |   string_col
-------------------------
0   carlo |   0000
1   luca  |   00
3   nanni |   0
4   nanno |   10000D
5   john  |   CO0123
```

I would like the resulting df to be

```
    col1  |   string_col 
-------------------------
0   carlo |   Nan
1   luca  |   Nan
3   nanni |   Nan
4   nanno |   10000D
5   john  |   CO0123
```

which I try to achieve with the following code:

```
has_zero_only = all(map(lambda x: x== '0', list(dftest['string_col'])))

dftest[has_zero_only]
```

Which doesn't work and throws an error at me:

```
~/Desktop/tiuk/network/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

~/Desktop/tiuk/network/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: False
```

I am pretty new to Pandas and I am sure there is a very clever way to do this -- thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
dftest['col2'] = dftest['col2'].mask(dftest['col2'].str.contains('^[0]+$'))
print (dftest)
    col1    col2
0  carlo     NaN
1   luca     NaN
2  nanni     NaN
3  nanno  10000D
4   john  CO0123
```

Or [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
dftest['col2'] =dftest['col2'].replace('^[0]+$', np.nan, regex=True)
```